# How to update the minimum & maximum number of running tasks in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to update the min and max number of tasks for a service in ECS in a lambda function (python with boto3). It looks like the closest thing is the desired count: `desiredCount`, but I don't think that is what I am after as my auto-scaling policy will change this anyway.

A bit more about my use case.

I have some containers on ECS of which poll a queue for jobs, and I to have some number of these always running during working hours, but then none running out of working hours. When load comes into the system my auto-scaling policy will scale out containers but a user would have to wait longer for this to happen when there are no containers, hence I want some always on during working hours.

I am also using AWS Fargate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you'll have to do it in 2 steps, using [**application auto-scaling** boto3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/application-autoscaling.html):

1. Create your ECS service as Application auto-scaling target with `register_scalable_target()` with for example `MinCapacity=3` and `MaxCapacity=100`. This call will return the scalable targer ARN.
2. Every evening call `register_scalable_target()` again with `MinCapacity=0` and every business day morning again with `MinCapacity=3`.

See the [`register_scalable_target()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/application-autoscaling.html#ApplicationAutoScaling.Client.register_scalable_target) documentation where it explicitly says:

> After you have registered a scalable target, you can use this operation to *update the minimum and maximum* values for its scalable dimension.

Your auto-scaling policy will then set `DesiredCapacity` within the *Min/MaxCapacity* boundaries where the MinCapacity will change from `0` to `3` during business hours and back to `0` after hours.

Hope that helps :)